# How do I resize facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some data and am using the `facet_grid`.

```
data <- read.csv(text='"type1","type2","time"
"A","T1",1182.17
"A","T2",1116.89
"A","T3",1088.66
"B","T1",1095.51
"B","T2",1106.09
"B","T3",1132.95
"C","T1",1094.11
"C","T2",1145.15
"C","T3",1159.14
')

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(data, aes(type2, time)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_discrete(
        expand=c(0,5)
    ) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(type1 ~ .)
```

Which gives me this nice plot

[image]

I'd like to reduce the height of individual lines, so I tried to add

```
scale_x_discrete(
    expand=c(0,5)
) +
```

Which gave me

[image]

How do I resize the facet rows? I tried `scale` and `space` parameters for `facet_grid`, but that made no effect. I also tried `heights`/`widths` of `facet_grid`, but they seem to be removed.

I am trying to acchieve something like this

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason that simply adjusting the height and width of the plot will not work? Just make it wider?

Comment: @alicemw That might be one solution. I didn't think of that, because I thought it will mess with proportions. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R GUIs (whether you're using the base GUI, rstudio, etc.) generally display plots at whatever aspect ratio fits the open plot window. Regardless of how the plot is displayed on your screen, you can use `ggsave()` to save the plot with your preferred dimensions, and ggplot will scale the plot to look nice at that aspect ratio (for the most part, sometimes you do have to edit text sizes and margins).

To save your plot at the dimensions you want, first make it a named object:

```
plot.name <- ggplot(data, aes(type2, time)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,5)) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(type1 ~ .)
```

then save it with a long width and short height:

```
ggsave(plot.name, #your ggplot
       "./example_plot.jpg", #filepath and name of file to save
        dpi = 300, 
        width = 6, #long width
        height = 3) #short height
```